# Azure pushnotification action modification

Tags: xamarin

I am using Azure notification hub to send push notification(xamarin forms). I have follow below example. and its working fine.

[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms#create-a-cross-platform-xamarinforms-application)

I have an issue when push notification coming when app is open. this sample shows and popup when notification coming when user using the app.

This is the JSON code

```
{
"text": "Message from Postman!",
"action": "action_a"
 }


   public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {

        if (message.Data.TryGetValue("action", out var messageAction))
                NotificationActionService.TriggerAction(messageAction);
    }
```

This shows popup called " ActionA action receved". I need to show my text message for this. I tried many ways but i couldn't modify it.

Comment: have you tried extracting the value for "text" instead of "action"?

Comment: I tried but not worked

Comment: "not worked" is not a helpful description of the problem.  What specifically did you try?  What was the specific result, error or exception?  Are you unable to retrieve the "text" value using `message.Data.TryGetValue("text", out var msgText);`?